# HW+SW combo to comfortably connect to NAS and Netflix

Tags: video, nas

0 down vote favorite I have a Synology NAS storing lots of movies and TV shows and I also have a Netflix account. In the past, I was using boxee box connected to my TV to play movies from the NAS via DLNA (unfortunately, boxee couldn't do Netlix for the past few years).

Since boxee died, I decided to get a HTPC running Win10 and Kodi to do the job, however, I couldn't get Netflix running on Kodi and I also wasn't able to find a skin that would be at least somehow as clear and ergonomic as the skin boxee used.

So, the question is: what HW/SW combination to use for this? Ideally, this should be all in one interface (one app or one device), controllable with a simple remote control and the skin should be really simple and minimalistic. I'm fine changing both HW and SW to achieve this, ideally for something that would meet the requirements above out of the box.

Note: I don't want to use anything like Chromecast where you got to have a phone to control the thing.

Comment: You might ask on [Software Recs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) about what you could run on your HTPC to accomplish your goals. If you do decided to ask a question there, please be sure to list the specs of the machine.

Comment: I don't insist on having a HTPC for this, as I wrote above, I'm fine changing the hardware that would do this: ideally for something that could do this out of the box.